# Xamarin.Android: Save Crash-Reports (Save StackTrace)

Tags: exception, logging, xamarin.android, stack-trace, crash-reports

I am trying to save my Error Message and StackTrace when my Xamarin.Android App crashes.

In Xamarin.iOS I can simply wrap my Main-Method in a Try-Catch-Block as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

Since there is no Main-Method in Xamarin.Android (just my MainLauncher Activity), I ask myself the question, if there is a similarly simple method to log the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to Log all Unhandled Exception:

In my MainLauncher Activity:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException;
```

and

```
private void HandleAndroidException(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Logger = new LogUtils();
            Logger.Log("ERROR: Unhandled Exception");
            Logger.Log("MESSAGE: " + e.Exception.Message);
            Logger.Log("STACKTRACE: " + e.Exception.StackTrace);
        }
```